# Get readonly to all textfield with the same ID

Tags: php, javascript

Im trying to Enable/Disable read-only property of textboxes in a colum with the same ID by clicking only one button but my code doesnt seem to work. Im still not familiar on how PHP works

code in PHP:

```
<input type='text' name='nTotal[$i]' value='$row->Total' size='5'  readonly='true' id='ntotal[$i]'>
```

code in javascript:

```
var a = document.getElementById(ntotal); //ntotal[$i] is the ID name of textbox in PHP
for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++){            

 if (a[i].readonly == 'false' ) {
        a[i].readonly = 'true';
         }

 else if(a[i].readonly == 'true'){ 
        a[i].readonly = 'false';
          }
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me a hint on why it doesnt work? Ive tried using name instead of ID but same outcome.

Comment: IDs in HTML are meant to be unique and can be assigned to only one element. Use classes to group elements and access them via javascript.

Comment: let me make it clear. Im trying to check the readonly propery on a textbox with a name textbox[$i] which [$i] stands for array number.so i need to know how does one  use it in a for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var arr = document.querySelectorAll('[id="'+ntotal+'"]');   
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i].getAttribute('readonly')=='readonly')
        arr[i].removeAttribute('readonly');
    else
        arr[i].setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you should use classes and `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById` as the latter will only return at most one element, based on the spec that says ids are unique.  Also, the `readOnly` (case sensitive, with a capital O) property is boolean, so comparing it to a string won't work.

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName(ntotal);
for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    a[i].readOnly = !a[i].readOnly;
}
```

You should use properties instead of attributes like every other answer suggests.  Much terser and more predictable.  The `readonly` attribute is boolean, so its presence alone is what matters, not the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix naming convention (ID must be unique and not only numbers) and use the getAttribute, setAttribute and remov eAttribute functions.

```html
<input type='text' name='nTotal' value='1' size='5' readonly='readonly' id='text_1'> 
<input type='text' name='nTotal' value='2' size='5' id='text_2'>
```

```js
var a = document.getElementsByName("nTotal");
for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
   isreadonly = a[i].getAttribute("readonly");
    if (isreadonly) {
      a[i].removeAttribute("readonly");                
    }
    else
    {
      a[i].setAttribute("readonly", "true");        
    }
}
```

Just have set up a working demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/wXbzq/

Or even better, use jQuery ( http://jquery.com ) ... you'll love it !

To disable in jQuery:

```js
$('nTotal').removeAttr('readonly');
```

To enable in jQuery:

```js
$('nTotal').attr('readonly', true);
```